# Kernel panic @MBP 15' 2015 happens almost one a day1

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

in the last weeks my system runs a kernel panic a day, more or less.

macbook pro 15 mid2015
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

The system was fresh install from scratch a few months ago and has been working fine until the last month or so.

There is no pirated software installed on it.

The only other weird thing happening is that rebooting the device after the kernel panic makes the macbook 747 spin up the fans full blown and sensor temperature goes up to almost 100º. Odd enough besides the noise the computer works fine after the kernel panic, until the next day or so.

Apps making the laptop almost take off land are onedrive and google drive.

```
    Wed Feb 26 05:34:20 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80004dc9bd): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8366e8cd, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000000000000f, CR3: 0x00000003d216b0e6, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000200, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000100000000
RSP: 0xffffff92135c3780, RBP: 0xffffff92135c37a0, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff92135c3848
R8:  0x000000100033a7cc, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff81bc9ac618, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff92135c3848, R13: 0xffffff802ea64608, R14: 0xffffff92135c3848, R15: 0xffffff92135c3860
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7f8366e8cd, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x000000000000000f, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92135c3250 : 0xffffff80003af57d 
0xffffff92135c32a0 : 0xffffff80004eb065 
0xffffff92135c32e0 : 0xffffff80004dc79a 
0xffffff92135c3350 : 0xffffff800035c9d0 
0xffffff92135c3370 : 0xffffff80003aef97 
0xffffff92135c3490 : 0xffffff80003aede3 
0xffffff92135c3500 : 0xffffff80004dc9bd 
0xffffff92135c3670 : 0xffffff800035c9d0 
0xffffff92135c3690 : 0xffffff7f8366e8cd 
0xffffff92135c37a0 : 0xffffff7f836670c5 
0xffffff92135c3910 : 0xffffff7f82735f84 
0xffffff92135c3950 : 0xffffff7f82736496 
0xffffff92135c3980 : 0xffffff7f8273cc36 
0xffffff92135c39c0 : 0xffffff7f8366deef 
0xffffff92135c39f0 : 0xffffff7f82733608 
0xffffff92135c3a80 : 0xffffff8000a8793c 
0xffffff92135c3ae0 : 0xffffff8000a85b60 
0xffffff92135c3b30 : 0xffffff8000a8eea2 
0xffffff92135c3c70 : 0xffffff80004974b6 
0xffffff92135c3d80 : 0xffffff80003b4dbc 
0xffffff92135c3dd0 : 0xffffff800038fb31 
0xffffff92135c3e50 : 0xffffff80003a424e 
0xffffff92135c3ef0 : 0xffffff80004c26d7 
0xffffff92135c3fa0 : 0xffffff800035d1b6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(404.14)[B90F7E9A-415C-38E6-BA28-823B4C530021]@0xffffff7f8272e000->0xffffff7f827d3fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[17A7EC3A-8985-3FD5-B08E-F1EF3DBE2ABC]@0xffffff7f8111d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(255.6.1)[DAEF78DB-6C43-35B5-A554-7B2F302C6352]@0xffffff7f8270d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4CEDE29C-2826-337B-8A0B-00C6F5270D9B]@0xffffff7f80c95000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(530.67)[C8F225BC-5B1C-343F-95D0-8E0DED5D740D]@0xffffff7f826bd000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[B0D3B0E7-4325-3EE3-817A-AD594AB286A6]@0xffffff7f816bb000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics(12.1)[C8FC723D-0F84-3BAF-B4A1-CB3AB22AA715]@0xffffff7f8362d000->0xffffff7f836a7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(255.6.1)[DAEF78DB-6C43-35B5-A554-7B2F302C6352]@0xffffff7f8270d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4CEDE29C-2826-337B-8A0B-00C6F5270D9B]@0xffffff7f80c95000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(530.67)[C8F225BC-5B1C-343F-95D0-8E0DED5D740D]@0xffffff7f826bd000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(404.14)[B90F7E9A-415C-38E6-BA28-823B4C530021]@0xffffff7f8272e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
18G1012

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sat Oct 12 00:02:19 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DFB5D0E2-3B41-3647-A48B-D704AFCC06B4
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8000100000
System model name: MacBookPro11,4 (Mac-06F11FD93F0323C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 86992260637653
last loaded kext at 32529180441719: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3.2 (addr 0xffffff7f839ee000, size 442368)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.0.14
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.0.14
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3.2
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.4
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.2
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.50.14
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.25.11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.50.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   12.1.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.50.14
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport  6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.8.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  12.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    212
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  408.250.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  138.4
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.260.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   202
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   740.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    528
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.54
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.50.14
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.50.14
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.67
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2440.2
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.270.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro11,4, BootROM 194.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.29f24
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisProItem, Intel Iris Pro, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.3 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Ethernet, en4
PCI Card: Apple 57762-A0, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@195,0,0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Ultra Fit
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter, Apple Inc., 1, 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Prime suspects would be Virtualbox & Soundflower.

Check for current versions of both -

[VB is 6.1.4](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
[Soundflower is 2.0b2](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/tag/2.0b2) .

Comment: There is in fact newer versions of both VBox and SoundFlower. Updated;
I'll let you know if this solve the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Kernel panic happened again 16 hours later of updating prime suspects.
Before the crashes it is always the same pattern: Chrome windows lose the content and start to appear plain grey, and big black lines cover some parts of the Screen.
Any recommendation on how to further advance to isolate the cause?

Additional info: 
- Screen was replaced a year ago under MacBook Pro Anti-Reflective Coating Repair Program. Device has been working fine for months since, so I think is not related.
- There are some 20 chrome windows open, but this has not  been a problem ever.
- Word is spinning ball,

Comment: Next steps would be to try without either of those installed at all, & also test a new, fresh admin account.

Comment: Just before the crashes black bars appears over the screen, and app windows lose the content and become grey and some other visual artefacts appear like blinking content, but if i do a screenshot the image is ok (no black bars or grey windows).
 Does it means it is something screen related ?

Comment: That sounds like a failing GPU, potentially an overheat. When was the last time the machine was stripped & cleaned?

Comment: It was open by Apple a few months ago for MacBook Pro Anti-Reflective Coating Repair Program, never anymore besides that. Lately I see temperature goes to to 90 degrees Celsius and beyond easily, but also sometimes the crash happens first time on the morning without being overheated at all...